# Are orbits of an affine algebraic monoid affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, semigroups-and-monoids, geometric-invariant-theory

Let us work over the complex numbers for simplicity. Let $M$ be an affine algebraic monoid and $X$ an affine variety on which $M$ acts regularly, i.e. there is a morphism $\alpha: M\times X\to X$. Let $x\in X$. To avoid missing any important conditions, let us for simplicity also assume that $M=\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is the monoid of square matrices. Is $M.x$ an affine variety?

Comment: The orbit need not be affine even if $M$ is an algebraic group.

Comment: I suppose I need it to be reductive. I edited the question. I am more interested in the "good" cases, though, so let's assume that $M$ is just the square matrices.

Comment: A constructible subset is in general not a variety, in any reasonable sense.

Comment: Do you want to assume that M contains 0?  Usually when talking about reductive linear algebraic monoids one assumes it has 0 and even all scalars.

Comment: Do you have a specific family of actions in mind?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: You're right, the reason is rather that it is a finite union of $G$-orbits.

Comment: I don't see why it's a finite union. Certainly this would depend on reductivity if it's true.

Comment: It is not in general a finite union. Let $M=\mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}$ and let $X$ be $M$ itself with the standard left action. Then $X = M \cdot \mathrm{Id}$. But there are infinitely many $G$-orbits: The rank $1$ matrices modulo the left action $GL_2$ are $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Possibly the result Jesko Hüttenhain is thinking of is that an orbit of a reductive group is affine if and only if its stabilizer subgroup is also reductive from Matsushima, Nagoya Math. J. 18 153-164 (1961)

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Curious. There must be some condition that is sufficient for the closure of any $G$-orbit to consist of only finitely many orbits. What would that be?

Comment: If $G$ is reductive, and its _Borel_ acts with an open orbit, then $G$ (and its Borel!) act with finitely many orbits.

Comment: Ah right, the orbit has to be spherical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orbits of a monoid aren't even varieties. Let $M$ be $\mathbb{A}^2$ with the monoid structure $(x_1, y_1) \cdot (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2)$. Let $M$ act on $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $(x,y) \cdot (t,u) = (xt, xyu)$. Then $M \cdot (1,1)$ is the image of the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$, which isn't a variety at all. Note that the unit group is $\mathbb{G}_m^2$, which is reductive.

Answer (score 4):

Let $SL_2$ act on ${\mathbb A}^2$. This has two orbits, $\{\vec 0\}$ and its complement, and the latter is not affine.

Comment: Conveniently the monoid of 2x2 matrices has 2 orbits on A^2, {0} and A^2.