# Action of the endomorphism monoid on an irreducible GL-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G=\mathrm{Gl}_n(\mathbb C)$ and $V$ an irreducible $G$-module on which $G$ acts polynomially. In other words, the algebraic group action of $G$ on the affine space $V$ extends to an algebraic action of the monoid $M=\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ on $V$. Now, let $v\in V$ and consider the subset $M.v\subseteq V$. I was told that $M.v$ is a variety, but noone could tell me a reference. I would be very happy if you could provide that. I am also curious whether it is an *affine* variety, or at least quasi-projective.

Comment: Lex Renner and Mohan Putcha are the experts in algebraic monoids. You might ask them.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I had [originally thought that this would translate to a general question about algebraic monoids](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142580/are-orbits-of-an-affine-algebraic-monoid-affine), but apparently it is rather special to the case of the general linear group (and the matrix monoid). Of course, I will probably follow your advice if this question gets no answers.

Comment: If it is closed it's easy to identify it as a scheme: Let $f : \mathbb{C}[V] \to \mathbb{C}[G]$ be defined by taking the $i$-th coordinate of $V$ to the $i$-th entry of $g.v$ (where $g$ is a matrix of variables). Your matrix orbit *wants* to be $Spec( \mathbb{C}[V]/\ker(f))$.

Comment: @AndyB: Yea, that's a really rare case unfortunately.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that: 1.$M$ is the monoid of $n \times n$ matrices. 2. $M.v=\{mv|m\in M\}$? If yes, it's look to easy. What did I miss?

Comment: @Rami: You are completely correct, that's what I mean. If it's easy to see that $M.v$ is a variety, please answer with a proof =).

Answer (score -1):

**As explained in the comments, the following Lemma is wrong:**

Let $f:W \to V$ be an homogeneous algebraic map (i.e. $f(\alpha v)=\alpha^k f(v)$ for some $k$).
Then the image of $f$ is closed sub-variety of $V$.

Proof: let $\bar f: \mathbb P(W) \to  \mathbb P(V)$ be the corresponding map of protective spaces. Since  $\mathbb P(W) $ is complete, the image of $\bar f$ is a closed sub-variety of $\mathbb P(V)$. So it is given be a collection of homogeneous polynomials on $V$. The same polynomials are the one that defines the image of $f$.

**The rest is probably correct now (I had to correct it too), but probably useless:**

The map $m \mapsto mv$ is homogeneous map (since the representation $V$ is irreducible).

Comment: The problem is that $\bar f$ is usually not well-defined. There could be matrices $m\in M\setminus\{0\}$ such that $mv=0$.

Comment: Does it really matter? The "deprojectivization" is a cone anyway and so it does include zero. What I mean is that you can just replace $f$ by $\tilde{f} \colon \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^n)/\mathrm{Ker}(f) \to V$.

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$? Do you mean the fiber over $0$? It does not have to be a sub-vectorspace. You might look at $\mathbb P(M\setminus f^{-1}(0))$, but that is probably no longer projective, so the argument will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "lemma" is false.  Take the map $(x,y) \to (x^2, xy)$.  The image is the union of $(0,0)$ and the set where $x$ is nonzero, which is not even a variety.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought we are dealing with linear representation, are we not?

Comment: Sorry, I made 2 mistakes. One of them is not crucial but the other seems to be so. As it written above the Lemma and its proof are wrong. :-(

Comment: @VítTuček: Sure we are dealing with linear actions, but that does not mean that for a fixed $v$, the morphism $M\to V$ mapping $m\mapsto m.v$ is a linear map. It only means that for a fixed $m$, the morphism $V\to V$ defined by $v\mapsto m.v$ is a linear map.

Comment: Right. I got confused by the notation; I thought for a moment that $m.v$ is the usual matrix multiplication.